# WMI Win32_PageFileSetting

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query

This code using WMI is yielding no results. I am testing on wind 7 with following WMI code.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PageFileSetting");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    { 

    }

// The for loop does not get executed.
```

Comment: This query requires the SeCreatePagefilePrivilege privilege.

Answer (score 3):

It should work. It is possible that you disabled "paging" on all your drives ? In that case    searcher.Get() returns an empty collection.

Comment: yes, looks like it, the advanced settings for page file is checked for the option - Automatically manage paging file size for all drives, but I do have set the total page file size for all drives to minimum of 16 mb and max of 16 gb. How will get these values using wmi ?

Comment: "WMI Code Creator v1.0" will surely help you :  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

Comment: Win32_PageFile, Win32_PageFileSetting, Win32_PageFileUsage & Win32_PageFileElementSetting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what information are you trying to gather, you can use `Select * from Win32_PageFileusage` which provides page file information.

I also faced problems `SELECT * FROM Win32_PageFileSetting` and most of the times it was returning empty collection.